# Can I filter a column based on the values of another column within the same tibble?

Tags: r, filter, max, tidyverse

I'm working with large datasets that have countless rows and am trying to automate some of my analyses. I mostly use #tidyverse to reduce the need of adding more packages, but I'm open to all suggestions. Consider the following tibble:

```
id <- rep(1:3, each = 48) # 3 individuals
time <- rep(seq(0, 23.5, by = .5), 3) 
count <- runif(48*3)
df <- tibble(id, time, count)
```

I'm trying to filter a 2-hour interval around the time of max count.
I can identify the time of max count using:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(count == max(count))
# OR
df$time[which.max(df$count)] # Only for 1 id, though
```

I am struggling to filter a range around the time of max count. I can identify the time correctly as a vector using Base R, but I can't filter for entire rows. I have not prepared for potential negative or missing values yet.

```
df$time[(which.max(df$count) - 2):(which.max(df$count) + 2)]
```

I'm calculating a few different variables using mutate(), so I want to incorporate this filter() into a pipe. I've attempted to use between(), match(), lead(), and lag(). which.max() has been the closest I've gotten to filtering the correct time duration. The following are a dead end and my closest, correct attempt:

```
# Listed max(count) in a new column; maybe use for matching?
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(peak = max(count))

# Partially selects time around max count, but not accurately.
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(time == time[(which.max(count) - 1.5):(which.max(count)+1.5)])
```

I've been coding for about a year now, but I think I'm missing some basic functions that I just don't know. Similar questions have been posted for SQL, but I have not found any regarding R or tidyverse. If you can help, I'd really appreciate it. Let me know if there's any clarification needed.

Comment: @akrun small mistake, but I fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `slice` after the grouping step

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    slice({i1 <- which.max(count)
            (i1 -2):(i1 + 2)})
# A tibble: 15 x 3
# Groups:   id [3]
#      id  time  count
#   <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     1   6.5 0.447 
# 2     1   7   0.785 
# 3     1   7.5 0.984 
# 4     1   8   0.133 
# 5     1   8.5 0.433 
# 6     2  14.5 0.266 
# 7     2  15   0.501 
# 8     2  15.5 0.965 
# 9     2  16   0.214 
#10     2  16.5 0.492 
#11     3  14   0.894 
#12     3  14.5 0.0388
#13     3  15   0.947 
#14     3  15.5 0.776 
#15     3  16   0.293
```

---

Or it can be made more compact

```
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    slice(which.max(count) + (-2:2))
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution using `row_number()`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(abs(row_number() - which.max(count)) <= 2)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 15 x 3
# Groups:   id [3]
      id  time  count
   <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1   5   0.574 
 2     1   5.5 0.763 
 3     1   6   0.985 
 4     1   6.5 0.701 
 5     1   7   0.281 
 6     2  21   0.0563
 7     2  21.5 0.274 
 8     2  22   0.978 
 9     2  22.5 0.560 
10     2  23   0.726 
11     3  12   0.889 
12     3  12.5 0.767 
13     3  13   0.999 
14     3  13.5 0.157 
15     3  14   0.896
```